How to create a variable splice query in Java neo4j Cypher-DSL，n:$label is not allowed in cypher?
I want to implement this neo4j query in java Cypher-DSL:
WITH "Person" as label
CALL apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (n) WHERE n:"+ label + " RETURN n",{})
YIELD value
RETURN value

But label is not allowed to use variables：
What is the proper usage of apoc.cypher.run with params?
How can I implement it using Cypher-DSL:
Cypher.with( Cypher.literalOf("Person").as("label"))
.call(
   ??,
   Cypher.mapOf()
)
.yield("value")
.returning("value")
.build();


I found the solution, using the concat or add method.

You can just do something like the Listing 4 example in the Cypher-DSL doc.
For example:
var people = Cypher.node("Person").named("people");
var statement = Cypher.match(people) 
    .returning(people)
    .build();

Another useful example shows how you can fetch Person nodes using Cypher-DSL and the Neo4j Java-Driver.
For example:
var people = Cypher.node("Person").named("people");
var statement = ExecutableStatement.of(
        Cypher.match(people)
            .returning(people)
            .build());

try (var session = driver.session()) { 
    var peopleList = session.executeRead(statement::fetchWith);

    // Do something with peopleList
    ...
}


What I mean is that label is a variable，like this: with ['test1','test2','test3'] as labels UNWIND labels AS label CALL apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (n) WHERE n:"+ label + " RETURN n",{}) 。I have found a solution, thanks
